# Is it possible to use Alamofire 3 with Swift 3?

Tags: swift, alamofire

My project was written in Swift 2.3 and running Alamofire 3.4.1.

Recently I attempted to upgrade my project to Swift 3 as well as its dependency Alamofire to version 4.

The problem is Alamofire changed some things which I can not fix at the moment.

So my question is, is it possible to use Alamofire 3 with Swift 3?

Thanks.

Comment: purely one man's opinion: **no**, you just have to upgrade; that's life  :/

Comment: So how realistic downloading  3.4.1 version and converting it to Swift 3 sounds ?